# discord.js Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I get this error:

```
botcommandsmoney.get('auction').run(bot, message, args, err, auctionhouse)
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
```

My code in index.js (start file) is this:

```js
//#region Consts

const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const fs = require('fs')
const userdata = require('./userdata.json')
const botcommands = new Discord.Collection()
const auctionhouse = new Object()

//#endregion

//#region Command Files

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./cmds/${file}`)

    botcommands.set(command.name, command)
}

const botcommandsfun = new Discord.Collection()
const commandFilesFun = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/fun/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFilesFun){
    const command = require(`./cmds/fun/${file}`)

    botcommandsfun.set(command.name, command)
}

const botcommandsinfo = new Discord.Collection()
const commandFilesInfo = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/info/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFilesInfo){
    const command = require(`./cmds/info/${file}`)

    botcommandsinfo.set(command.name, command)
}

const botcommandsitems = new Discord.Collection()
const commandFilesItems = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/items/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFilesItems){
    const command = require(`./cmds/items/${file}`)

    botcommandsitems.set(command.name, command)
}

const botcommandsmisc = new Discord.Collection()
const commandFilesMisc = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/misc/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFilesMisc){
    const command = require(`./cmds/misc/${file}`)

    botcommandsmisc.set(command.name, command)
}

const botcommandsmod = new Discord.Collection()
const commandFilesmod = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/mod/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFilesmod){
    const command = require(`./cmds/mod/${file}`)

    botcommandsmod.set(command.name, command)
}

const botcommandsmoney = new Discord.Collection()
const commandFilesmoney = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/money/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFilesmoney){
    const command = require(`./cmds/money/${file}`)

    botcommandsmoney.set(command.name, command)
}

//#endregion

bot.login('my token, i\'m not gonna tell you it')

bot.on('ready', () => {
    bot.user.setActivity('*help', { type: "WATCHING" })
})

bot.on('message', message => {


    //#region Setting up data
        if(!userdata[message.author.id]) {
            userdata[message.author.id] = {
                name: message.author.username,
                referer: null,
                joinguild: {
                    guildid: message.guild.id,
                    guildname: message.guild.name
                },
                userconfig: {
                    commands: {
                        amount: 0,
                        category: {
                            fun: 0,
                            info: 0,
                            moderation: 0,
                            misc: 0,
                            money: 0,
                            item: 0,
                            premium: 0
                        }
                    },
                    messages: 1,
                    coupons: 0,
                    passive: false
                },
                profile: {
                    rob: {
                        robs: 0,
                        successrobs: 0,
                        failedrobs: 0,
                        heists: 0
                    },
                    pay: {
                        payed: 0,
                        recieved: 0
                    },
                    account: {
                        status: "A waffle bot user!",
                        skin: "default",
                        food: "waffles",
                        wishlist: [],
                        funfact: "A cool waffle bot user!",
                        pfp: message.author.avatarURL()
                    }
                }
            }
            fs.writeFile("./userdata.json", JSON.stringify(userdata), err => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
              });
        }
        var item1id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        var item2id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        while(item2id == item1id){
            var item2id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        }
        var item3id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        while(item3id == item2id || item3id == item1id){
            var item3id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        }
        if(!auctionhouse){
            auctionhouse = {
                item1: {
                    name: "Spot One",
                    seller: null,
                    startingprice: 0,
                    currentprice: 0,
                    winningbidder: null,
                    id: item1id
                },
                item2: {
                    name: "Spot Two",
                    seller: null,
                    startingprice: 0,
                    currentprice: 0,
                    winningbidder: null,
                    id: item2id
                },
                item3: {
                    name: "Spot Three",
                    seller: null,
                    startingprice: 0,
                    currentprice: 0,
                    winningbidder: null,
                    id: item3id
                }
            }
        }

    //#endregion
    
    //#region Setting Up RichEmbeds
        function err(error){
            embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('<a:no:676180589895876611> ' + error)
            .setColor("RED")
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
        function success(msg){
            embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('<a:yes:676180565434695747> ' + msg)
            .setColor("GREEN")
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
    //#endregion
    
    const args = message.content.substring("*").split(" ");
    switch(args[0]){
        case `*help`:
            botcommandsinfo.get('help').execute(message, args)
            break;
        case '*snipe':
            botcommandsinfo.get('snipe').execute(bot, message, args, err)
            break;
        case '*auctionhouse':
            botcommandsmoney.get('auction').execute(bot, message, args, err, auctionhouse)
            break;
    }
})
bot.snipes = new Map()

//#region Firing Events
    bot.on('messageDelete', function(message, channel) {
        bot.snipes.set(message.channel.id, {
            content: message.content,
            author: message.author,
            image: message.attachments.first() ? message.attachments.first().proxyURL : null
        })
    })

//#endregion
```

All of my other commands work, (snipe and help) but the *auctionhouse does not.

My code for the *auctionhouse command:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "Help command!",
    execute(bot, message, args, err, auctionhouse){
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Auction House')
    .setDescription('To bid on an item, run `*bid <id> <amount>`.')
    .addField(`${auctionhouse.item1.name} - $${auctionhouse.item1.currentprice} - ID: \`${auctionhouse.item1.id}\``)
    .addField(`${auctionhouse.item2.name} - $${auctionhouse.item2.currentprice} - ID: \`${auctionhouse.item2.id}\``)
    .addField(`${auctionhouse.item3.name} - $${auctionhouse.item3.currentprice} - ID: \`${auctionhouse.item3.id}\``)
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

This is the directory listing: [stack overflow won't let me add images yet :( so this is an imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVvGo.png)

Details:

Runtime: Node.JS v12
Discord.JS Version: 12.0.0
OS: Windows 10 Home 64 Bit
Ram: 8GB, 2GB dedicated
My Discord: Aawesome#6969

Comment: What's inside your `auction.js`? I bet the `name` there is not `auction`, possibly you copied it from another file and forgot to update the name. So, `botcommandsmoney.set` will be called with something other than `auction`, and `botcommandsmoney.get('auction')` will return `undefined`, hence why `butcommandsmoney.get('auction').run()` throws the error `cannot read property 'run' of undefined`.

Comment: @CherryDT just double checked, no, it's `auction.js` for sure.

Comment: No I said: Check what `name` property is set _inside_ of `auction.js`. Your code assigns the bot functions by their name property, not by their filename.

Comment: oh thank you! it's 'help'!

Comment: You are welcome. (This question is probably going to be closed now.)

Comment: Could you write a reply so i could mark it as answered?

Comment: Actually I close-voted it as "not reproducible or caused by a typo" because I thought it probably won't be of much value for others given what the problem was at the end. But on second thought, yes it may be useful after all, especially now with your edit - OK, writing an answer

Comment: seconding that close reason; this is very unlikely to help anybody else. There's also at least a billion existing "cannot read property X of Y" questions in the JS tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `botcommandsmoney.get('auction').run(...)` throws the error `Cannot read property 'run' of undefined` which indicates that `botcommandsmoney.get('auction')` returns `undefined`. I would therefore assume that no `auction` bot command was defined.

We can see that you are loading all the files in `./cmds/money` and setting their export as command in `botcommandsmoney` using the line `botcommandsmoney.set(command.name, command)`. It would appear that the piece of information that defines how the command is called inside `botcommandsmoney` is coming from `command.name`, i.e. the property `name` inside the file.

Looking at your `auction.js` file though, we can see that the property `name` has value `help` instead of `auction`! So, `botcommandsmoney.get('help')` and not `botcommandsmoney.get('auction')` would return your command... I assume that this is a copy-paste error, you probably copied the file from another command and forgot to update the `name` inside of it even though you renamed the file itself.

Therefore, the fix is to change `name: 'help'` to `name: 'auction'` in `auction.js`.